# Stuck with onclick and document.GetElementById

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

I just began JavaScript and I've been stuck for a few hours now with an `onclick` which is not working, or maybe it's the `document.getElementById`. What I want to do is hide the `div` when I click on it.

If anyone can explain me what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful!

```js
function closing() {
    var closecook = document.getElementById("cookies");
    closecook.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#cookies{ 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookies" onclick="closing()">
  Our website is using cookies, click here to close this message.
</div>
```

Here's my relevant HTML markup:

```
<body>
<div id="cookies" onclick="closing()">
    Our website is using cookies, click here to close this message.
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is [working](https://jsbin.com/tosopiyage/4/edit?html,css,js,output) for me.

Comment: Yeah, are there any errors in your console? Is the source of the script actually `functions.js`?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource `functions.js` _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Apparently this was a problem with my browser... Everything works fine now. Seems like refreshing the page a few times is not enough to take my updates into account...

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your "script" block at the end of your body, not outside of it!
2. alter you the function "closing" to something like this:

   `function closing() {
       var closecook = document.getElementById("cookies");
       console.log(closecook);
       closecook.style.display = "none";
   }`
3. In your browser: open the console by hitting "F12" or right-click anywhere in your browser and select "inspect element" then choose "console".
4. Now execute your function by clicking on the div.

If you see a "null" in the console: the problem comes from "document.getElementById("");".

If you do not see anything pop up in the console, your javascript file is not loaded properly. Make sure there is no typo in the file name! (Linux is case-sensitiv!).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I am not sure why your answer has been downvoted, but please note that the questioner has confirmed that his/her trouble was in fact a browser caching problem.

Comment: Might be helpful to others to say that 1 fixed my issue. Placing at the bottom of body, which makes sense.